# Sign in popup when debugging asp.net win forms application in Visual studio 2022 with Windows authentication

Tags: webforms, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, windows-authentication, anonymous

When I attempt to debug an asp.net web forms application with Chrome, Firefox or edge, I get a sign in popup which I cannot get past.
I am using Windows authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

None of my breakpoints get hit.
In the web.config I am denying anonymous users:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
```

I have the solution set to use IISExpress with anonymous set to disabled.

If I set this to enabled and allow anonymous users in the web.config I do not get the sign in page, however I am not authenticated which causes other issues.
So when anonymous is disabled, the application still thinks I an anonymous and denies further entry.

A colleague is running the same application without issue, all settings within visual studio are the same, which is strange.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you put in your AD credentials into the popup, does it work? If so, then it's just a matter of the browser not automatically sending your credentials.